# I have a single row in treeview.How to split that into 2 r 3 rows of text?

Tags: c#

Am using ASP.NET(C#)

I have a single row in treeview.
Myself using asp:treeview here.
How to split that into 2 r 3 rows of text?

Example:

```
Kalaiselvan is new to Dotnet Help him bla bla bla here goes here!!
```

I need this text as follows;

kalaiselvan is new to dotnet

Help him bla bla bla here

goes here!!!...

Comment: Sign is removed, Please refer the FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures

Answer (score 0):

use the Split() method on that string and Split(',') will be the delimiter from there loop thru

```
 string strTemp = "Kalaiselvan is new to Dotnet,Help him!!";
 string[] strarrTemp = strTemp .Split(',');
 foreach(string s in strarrTemp)
 {
   Console.WriteLine(s);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Kraze..But am using treeview here..i cant do tat..i fetched the datas from sql server so that a single node will contain a huge text in a single row..i need to split in that,a single row into atleast 2 rows..hope u understand my question!!..